# Populating multiple variables in each iteration with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a number of variables and my intention is to populate each of them in a number of iterations while each need a different expression in order to extract their values. A rough equivalent of what I am trying to do is the following for loop.

```
pairs = {('Ams', 'Rot') : 10, ('Del', 'Utr') : 12, ('Ams', 'Utr') : 14, ('Del', 'Rot') : 16}

var_1 = []
var_2 = []
var_3 = []
var_4 = []

for i in range(3):
    for (j, k) in pairs:
        var_1.append(i)
        var_2.append(j)
        var_3.append(k)
        var_4.append(pairs[(j, k)])

df = {'Var_1' : var_1, 'Var_2' : var_2, 'Var_3' : var_3, 'Var_4' : var_4}
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
print(df)
```

My Desired output:

```
    Var_1 Var_2 Var_3  Var_4
0       0   Ams   Rot     10
1       0   Del   Utr     12
2       0   Ams   Utr     14
3       0   Del   Rot     16
4       1   Ams   Rot     10
5       1   Del   Utr     12
6       1   Ams   Utr     14
7       1   Del   Rot     16
8       2   Ams   Rot     10
9       2   Del   Utr     12
10      2   Ams   Utr     14
11      2   Del   Rot     16
```

However, I am curious to know whether there is a more efficient way of doing this in particular with `pandas`. In the end I would like to create a pandas DataFrame of the following dictionary.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame({n: range(3) for n in names})`?

Comment: @not_speshal Thank you very much. Maybe I oversimplified a bit, but I need to execute different expressions like 4 different expression to extract the values for each variable here.

Comment: Could you update your question to provide a more representative example? It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @not_speshal Yes you are right. I will try to update it shortly.

Comment: @not_speshal I updated the question and sorry for the inconvenience it may have caused.

Comment: what's "names" here and how is it relevant?

Comment: @enke Oh updated again. It was left out from the previous codes.

Comment: Missing one line at the end?

Comment: @Corralien No that's it. For me it's giving the desired output.

Comment: Why there is no `Del   Rot     16`?

Comment: @Corralien My bad again, I updated the print, I think it makes sense now.

Comment: Yes it's really better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a solution based on indexes:

As you have a dict, create a dataframe with data are values and indexes are the keys. In your case, you have tuple keys so use the index will be a `pd.MultiIndex`. At this point you have `Var_2`, `Var_3` and `Var_4`.

The tricky part is to generate `Var_1` from this dataframe. Repeat your index 3 times and reindex the dataframe. All values are duplicated. So you have 3 x (Ams, Rot, 10), 3 x (Del, Utr, 12) and so on. Now if you group this duplicated rows together, you can use `cumcount` to create an ID (0 -> first instance, 1 -> second instance, ...). Finally sort your dataframe by index (`Var_1`) and reset it to get your expected result.

```
# Part 1: create Var_2, Var_3 and Var_4
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(pairs.keys(), names=['Var_2', 'Var_3'])
df = pd.DataFrame({'Var_4': pairs.values()}, index=mi).reset_index()

# Part 2: create Var_1
df = df.reindex(df.index.repeat(3))
df = df.set_index(df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).cumcount().rename('Var_1')) \
       .sort_index().reset_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> df
    Var_1 Var_2 Var_3  Var_4
0       0   Ams   Rot     10
1       0   Del   Utr     12
2       0   Ams   Utr     14
3       0   Del   Rot     16
4       1   Ams   Rot     10
5       1   Del   Utr     12
6       1   Ams   Utr     14
7       1   Del   Rot     16
8       2   Ams   Rot     10
9       2   Del   Utr     12
10      2   Ams   Utr     14
11      2   Del   Rot     16
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Can you please add some explanation to your code?

Comment: @AnoushiravanR. I updated my answer. I hope you will understand my explanation, it's not my best skill :)

Comment: Thank you very much, and I truly appreciate all the time and efforts you spent on my question. It's really good and I need to take my time to understand it. As I am so new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use `dict-comprehension` to setup that easily

```
names = ['var_1', 'var_2', 'var_3', 'var_4']
values = {n: range(3) for n in names}
df = pd.DataFrame(values)
```

```
   var_1  var_2  var_3  var_4
0      0      0      0      0
1      1      1      1      1
2      2      2      2      2
```

But creating a dataframe with identical columns is a bit strange, that doesn't have much informations

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. For this problem I need different expression to extract the values for each variable, can you please let me know how I could see to that. Like for example `var_1` is going to be `0, 1, 2`, `var_2` is going to multiply it by a constant and etc.

Comment: You can't ask something very simple, then say "in fact it isn't what I need", please update the initial post (question) with a real usecase, and more precise than the comment you just wrote

Comment: I changed the initial data structure from an empty dictionary to 4 empty list for the sake of simplification. But it does not matter at all.

Answer (score 1):

We could also create a DataFrame with `pairs` (this will create a DataFrame with one row and MultiIndex columns), `repeat` it (since we want to repeat the same row 3 times, we use `Index.repeat` + `reindex` to repeat 3 times). Then we use `reset_index` + `rename_axis` + `reset_index` to get "Var_1" correctly named and ordered. Then `melt` will deliver the data in the desired shape. Finally, we could use `sort_values` + `reset_index` to get a DataFrame the same as the one you built.

```
tmp = pd.DataFrame(pairs, index=[0])
out = (tmp.reindex(tmp.index.repeat(3))
       .reset_index(drop=True)
       .rename_axis('Var_1')
       .reset_index()
       .melt(id_vars=['Var_1'], var_name=['Var_2', 'Var_3'], value_name='Var_4')
       .sort_values(by='Var_1')
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output:

```
    Var_1 Var_2 Var_3  Var_4
0       0   Ams   Rot     10
1       0   Del   Utr     12
2       0   Ams   Utr     14
3       0   Del   Rot     16
4       1   Ams   Rot     10
5       1   Del   Utr     12
6       1   Ams   Utr     14
7       1   Del   Rot     16
8       2   Ams   Rot     10
9       2   Del   Utr     12
10      2   Ams   Utr     14
11      2   Del   Rot     16
```

Or you could write a list comprehension and build a DataFrame with a list. This is very similar to what you already have. The only difference is instead of building 4 separate lists, it builds one list.

```
tmp = [[i, j, k, v] for i in range(3) for (j, k), v in pairs.items()]
df = pd.DataFrame(tmp, columns=['Var_1', 'Var_2', 'Var_3', 'Var_4'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = (pd.DataFrame({n: pd.Series(pairs) for n in range(3)})
        .stack()
        .rename_axis(["Var_2", "Var_3", "Var_1"])
        .rename("Var_4")
        .reset_index()
        .sort_values("Var_1", ignore_index=True)
        .sort_index(axis=1)
        )

>>> df

   Var_1 Var_2 Var_3  Var_4
0       0   Ams   Rot     10
1       0   Del   Utr     12
2       0   Ams   Utr     14
3       0   Del   Rot     16
4       1   Ams   Rot     10
5       1   Del   Utr     12
6       1   Ams   Utr     14
7       1   Del   Rot     16
8       2   Ams   Rot     10
9       2   Del   Utr     12
10      2   Ams   Utr     14
11      2   Del   Rot     16
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(pairs, name='Var_4').to_frame()]*3, keys=range(3),
               names=['Var_1', 'Var_2', 'Var_3']).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    Var_1 Var_2 Var_3  Var_4
0       0   Ams   Rot     10
1       0   Del   Utr     12
2       0   Ams   Utr     14
3       0   Del   Rot     16
4       1   Ams   Rot     10
5       1   Del   Utr     12
6       1   Ams   Utr     14
7       1   Del   Rot     16
8       2   Ams   Rot     10
9       2   Del   Utr     12
10      2   Ams   Utr     14
11      2   Del   Rot     16
```

Comment: I edited your code to get the expected output. I hope it's OK for you?